# How to retrieve bean value from JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a jsp page, where i want to display some values from a list of "order" objects from a POJO.

```
 <c:forEach items="${orders}" var="orders">
 <form name="employee" action="FrontController" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="command" value="employee">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <tr>
        <td>${orders}>
```

whenever i use the dot operator on orders, to get the value. (for example orders.height), it returns and error, it might be because i'm trying to access a list and not an object.

```
        <td>${orders}>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

is there any way to get an attribute out from my order object.

here is the servlet code, the creates the order list.

```
@Override
String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws LoginSampleException {
    try{
        ArrayList<OrderSample> orders =UserMapper.showOrders();
         request.setAttribute("orders", orders);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

    return "employeepage";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `var` another name like `var="order"`.
Then access it with `${order.id}` or whatever other properties `OrderSample` has.

PS: `OrderSample` has to have getter methods for properties you want to access.